# jruby/ActiveRecord/jdbcsqlite3/jruby-poi: From Rails to command-line script: How to remove/convert single element array's?

Tags: arrays, activerecord, jdbc, jruby

Busy migrating a report generation from Rails(Web) to a jruby command-line script.
Using:

- jruby-1.7.11
- ActiveRecord & ActiveSupport: 3.0.6
- jdbc-sqlite3: sqlitejdbc-3.7.9.jar (with custom sqlite3.8 shared library)
- jruby-poi: 0.9

Problem:

- ResultTable.find_by_sql returns an array containing single length array's in stead of string's.   ['country_NLD']   in stead of 'country_NLD'

Under Rails this seams to be working OK.

Questions:

- How do I convert a single element array to a NON array even when its deep down in an other array?
- I know that Postgress active record-jdbc-adapter has a setting called '...array.raw'. Is there some setting for SQLite3 available?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you did miss an important piece to mention: **ActiveRecord-JDBC-Adapter**'s (gem) version ...

if you happen to be on 1.2.x I do recommend an upgrade to 1.3.x which shall have this incompatibility fixed, otherwise you should report the issue.